# how to install QPID C++ Message broker in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, qpid

I have tried using the commands as

1) sudo apt-get update

2) sudo apt-get install python-qpid

3) sudo apt-get install qpidd

But from the third command, it says "E:Unable to locate package qpidd"

Any, way to install it in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Also, has to install qpidd, qpid tools.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qpid/released
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -y qpidd qpid-tools
```